# DateTime EditorFor Template - Setting id and name attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, editorfor

I am trying to make a form that lets the user choose a date range to view some stats.  I can't get the datetime to show up as just the date in the textboxes unless I am using the 'Alternate DateTime Editor Template I Tried' but then I don't get it hooked up to the form because it doesn't have an id or name attribute.

What am I doing wrong?

### DateTime Editor Template

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<DateTime>
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p, new { @class = "datepicker span2" })
```

### Alternate DateTime Editor Template I Tried

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<DateTime>
<input class="datepicker span2" type="text" value="@Model.ToShortDateString()" />
```

### My Model

```
public class ManageStatsModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime MinDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime MaxDate { get; set; }
}
```

### Markup on Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Stats", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.MinDate)
    <span> - </span>
    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.MaxDate)
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<DateTime>
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "datepicker span2" })
```

The `TextBox` helper will build the appropriate name from the model/template hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks! Surprisingly, not many people (even on SO) seem to pick up the reference :)